# Netbeans: why need to rebuild project to update the 'dist' folder?

Tags: netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 6.7 and notice that the jar file in the 'dist' folder will not get updated until I click on "clean and build"

This is quite annoying; I expected Netbeans to just regenerate the JAR file everytime I save a file.

Does anyone experience this issue? If so, how do you make sure the jar file is always up to date?

Comment: I believe that this is expected behavior. When you save, the code is executable using the NetBeans Run command, however the distributable JAR is only produced when you Build or Clean and Build.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a build instead of clean build... I can see why they do not generate the jar on save it would be a fairly "expensive" operation especially for those of us that save far more often then we run.

Other than build or clean build I don't know of a way to do what you want.  [Here is an article on the topic.](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave#What_is_not_Compile_on_Save)